# How to apply theme color of cell in excel using apple script

Tags: excel, applescript

I am using Apple script. My problem is, how can i change the theme color of cells to first accent theme color.

tell interior object of cell "A1" 
 set color index to 5 
 set theme color 9 
end tell

In this script color index is set but theme color is not set .
Please help me.
i am waiting for your replay.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set theme color of interior object of cell "A1" to first accent theme color
```

Comment: Hi, My question is , how to set theme color on conditional formatting. your script is run successfully on cell but I want to apply theme color on condition formatting rule.                       set f1 to make new format condition at range "B4:B7" with properties {format condition:text string}  \n tell interior object of f1 \n     set theme color to second accent theme color \n end tell